# Assigning the arguments object to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I'm quite new to Javascript and was wondering about the `arguments` object (as probably anyone does who is new to the language) using NodeJS.

Consider this snippet which simply implements `printf` style formatting

```
function format(formatString) {
  var i = 1;
  return formatString.replace(regex, function(match) {
    switch(match) {
      case "%s": return arguments[i++];
    }
  });
}
```

Calling the function `format("Hi my name is %s. Im %s years old", "Jon", "30")` results in following output `My name is 11. Im My name is %s. Im %s years old years old`.

Researching about `arguments` showed that we are not dealing with a "real" array here and that using `Array.slice(arguments)` actually produces one. However, I'm struggling with following fact:

Performing this simple assignment `var args = arguments` and than referencing `args` instead of `arguments` lets my code work perfectly (I stumbled across this inspecting the NodeJS source for `util.format`)

My Question is now, what kind of black magic is V8 practicing here? Is there any conversion performed in the background? And if, what kind of conversion? Node tells me that both variable are of type `object`.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: What is `regex`? Does it have a `g` flag?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification james. Scope in nested callbacks is one of the concepts im having to get used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. `arguments` only means anything inside the function it is in.  In your case, `arguments` is referencing the arguments of the anonymous function.  You need to capture the arguments in the parent scope. Something like:

```
function format(formatString) {
  var i = 1, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return formatString.replace(/%[a-z]/gi, function(match) {
    switch(match) {
      case "%s": return args[i++];
    }
  });
}
format("Hi my name is %s. Im %s years old", "Jon", "30");

// Output: "Hi my name is Jon. Im 30 years old"
```